# Finding power with Drag Force equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, power, drag

The mass of the car is 1500 kg. The shape of the body is such that its aerodynamic drag coefficient is $C_D=0.330$ and the frontal area is $2.50 m^2$. Assuming that the drag force is proportional to $v^2$ and neglecting other sources of friction, calculate the power required to maintain a speed of $100 km/h$ as the car climbs a long hill sloping is $3.20^\circ$.
Use the formula:
$$
F_D=\frac{1}{2}C_D\rho_{air}Av^2 
$$
where $\rho_{air}=1.2kg/m^3$

I don't know how to incorporate power into the formula. I get that $F_d$ is proportional to $v^2$ so am I able to cancel them out?

Comment: You just have to use this formula for drag as a given expression for drag. But do you know how to calculate power in general?

Comment: P = w/delta t i think

Answer (score 1):

Power is defined as $P = F \cdot v$ where $F$ is the driving force and $v$ is the velocity of the moving object. In this case, determine the values of both $F$ and $v$, and use this to calculate the power.

If you need additional help, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: How do i solve for the force exactly? Do i substitute v^2 for Fd?

Comment: Not quite. You've provided the equation for force above ($F_D = \frac{1}{2} C_D \rho_{air} A v^2$), and you have the values of each of those variables, so you can use that equation to find the force.

Comment: nevermind didn't see that they gave velocity

Comment: ...and don't forget the slope it's climbing...

Answer (score -2):

$HP = (F*v) = [(1/2)*Cd*ρ*A*v^2]*v = (1/2)*Cd*ρ*A*v^3 $

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how you arrived at this equation and the significance of the variables in it.